# Top Margin pulls down the parent as well

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav><ul class='container'>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Categories</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>How to Play</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
    <article id="showcase">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </article>
</body>
</html>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hjYzs/

What's wrong? `<h1>`'s margin seems to be pulling its parent `article` down too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey now give to `#showcase overflow:hidden` in your css

```
#showcase{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hjYzs/1/)**

this is the Collapsing Margins
and **[more info](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)**

Comment: Weird, why does it act like that?

Comment: It's called collapsing margin http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hjYzs/2/

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong here, this is normal behaviour. Margins are meant to collapse - it's part of the spec.

I believe the idea is that the top and bottoms margins of adjacent elements are never supposed to add together, the largest margin is the one that is shown.

Steps I normally take:

1. Remove default top margins
2. Use padding over margins whereever possible.
3. I also often add a 1px padding to elements to contain top and bottom margins - especially if the parent has a different background colour.

Hope that helps for future :)